# Suppose method M1 calls method M2 within a program.Does the order of method definition make any difference?

Tags: java, methods, static-methods, netbeans-platform

Please explain me from basics.I am a beginner in Java programming

Comment: Hello. Can you show an example? It's quite hard to understand. If you talk about order of method in a class, there's not any difference except that it's often ordered from public to private method.

Comment: There are only two possible orders for the two methods. You could easily try both and see if it makes any difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no. It does not matter order of method declaration. Here is a working example:

```
class Foo{

    public static void main(String[] args){
       Bar myInstance = new Bar();
       myInstance.M1(); 

    }
 }

class Bar{

   public M1() {
   // do something
    System.out.println(“Hey! Someone called me! I’m here!”)
    M2();
   }

    public M2() {
    System.out.println(“Hey! Someone called me! I’m here!”)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other languages in Java doesn't matter the order in which you define the methods.

M1 can call M2 even if M2 is defined later than M1.